# SBT - Dependency missing

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I did few changes in build.sbt files of working project. After changes I did `sbt clean update` it working fine. But While running `sbt clean compile` it showing compilation errors regarding squants package.

My build.sbt contains

```
"com.squants" % "squants_2.10" % "0.2.3" % Compile,
```

And I took the dependency graph tree "dependencyBrowseGraph". It not showing anything regarding squants package. What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Can you please share the compile error message.

Comment: MyClass.scala:3,  not found: object squants
[error] import squants.Time
[error]        ^

Comment: Its working fine from my side. I added this in build.sbt `libraryDependencies += "com.squants" % "squants_2.10" % "0.2.3" % Compile`
And in code imported the package. Everything compiles fine. I am using scala version 2.11.8. 
1. What is your scala version
2. Can you share the buid.sbt file, I guess the problem is in the sbt file. The squants library is not resolved properly by sbt

Comment: Putting 2.10 library in 2.11 project sounds risky.

Answer (score 0):

It happen because of missing squants library in one of the modules in same project.